# How do I write the code once, then link to existing XCode or Android project?

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm interested in MVVMCross as a means of developing a library that can be compiled and linked to an existing iOS and Android project.

Is this possible using MVVMCross. The library would contain

- Models
- Persistence / Data Access Code
- Web service calls
- Business Logic

Is this possible?

Cheers

Tobin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that, the difficulties doesn't justify the effort. It's actually much easier if you rewrite the iOS and Android with Xamarin.

'Rewriting' has very bad reverberations, especially in the ear of your boss, but due to how Xamarin works, it's much easier than you might think, here is why:

If you plan to use Xamarin and MVVMCross to build a shared Core project and use it in your existing XCode and Android projects (assuming this is technically possible) you would have to strip out pretty much of the implementation from your existing projects and move it to the Xamarin MVVMCross Core project.

Your existing XCode and Android projects would remain with mostly just the UI. But this is very similar to as re-writing the apps with Xamarin, because with Xamarin you would build your UI using the same native tools as you already had.

If you want to use Xamarin, the best I think would be just recreate iOS and Android apps with Xamarin. You have the UI already done and you can port it easily, there's no need to rewrite the UI layouts.
However, you will probably have to add and change few things in the UI, but it is all for a good reason.

I suggest you first read about MVVM design pattern in general, if you haven't.
Then look to MVVMCross videos http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/ and Wiki https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki

Comment: Thanks, having used Xamarin last night I can see that that's the angle they're taking. And re-building the apps in Xamarin would be necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't call it rewriting actually, more like porting :D

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "into an existing xamarin.iOS or xamarin.android project" then yes, that should be straight-forward to do.

If you mean "into an existing Xcode or Java project" then this is considerably harder (super guru level harder) - as Xamarin's tools do not support library generation out-of-the-box. A middle ground easier route in this case may be to look at using the xamarin sharpie and jar import tools to wrap your existing ObjC and java code.

Comment: Thanks, knowing that Xamarin doesn't support Library generation was the key.